# Excluding certain patterns in a regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a Regex in C# to exclude certain patterns within a string.

These are the types patterns I want to accept are: "%00" (Hex 00-FF) and any other character without a starting '%'. The patterns I would like to exclude are: "%0" (Values with a starting % and one character after) and/or characters "&<>'/".

So far I have this

```
Regex correctStringRegex = new Regex(@"(%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})|[^%&<>'/]|(^(%.))", 
                                     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Below are examples of what I'm trying to pass and reject.

Passing String `%02This is%0A%0Da string%03`
Reject String `%0%0Z%A&<%0a%`

If a string doesn't pass all the requirements I would like to reject the whole string completely.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean "accept" or "except?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
^(?:%[0-9a-f]{2}|[^%&<>'/])*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^             # Start of string
(?:           # Match either
 %[0-9a-f]{2} # %xx
|             # or
 [^%&<>'/]    # any character except the forbidden ones
)*            # any number of times
$             # until end of string.
```

This ensures that `%` is only matched when followed by two hexadecimals. Since you're already compiling the regex with the `IgnoreCase` flag set, you don't need `a-fA-F`, either.

Comment: Hey Tim, I currently have this in my code. String xyz = "%19%10as%"; and im doing a bool x = correctStringRegex.IsMatch(xyz); and I am still getting a true for this string am i doing something wrong?

Comment: After looking at this response, i think you need to define the problem slightly differently.  You want to get a Pass/Fail value for the entire string, so long as it doesn't contain any invalid combinations.  Valid combinations are %##, with ## being in Hex, and any char other than %(by itself), &, <, >, `, or /.  This is a different requirement than matching the patterns, or filtering them out.

Comment: @Miguel: That string tests `False` with this regex. Are you really using the entire regex (especially the `^` and `$` parts are important?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, given the comments so far, I think you need a different problem definition.  You want to pass or fail a string, using regex, based on whether or not the string contains any invalid patterns.  Im assuming a string will fail if there is ANY invalid pattern, rather than the reverse of a string passing if there is any valid pattern.

As such, I would use this regex: `%(?![0-9a-f]{2})|[&<>'/]`

You would then run this in such a way that a string is invalid if you GET a match, a valid string will not have any matches in this set.

A quick explanation of a rather odd regex.  The format `(?!)` tells the regex "Match the previous symbol if the symbols in this set DONT follow it" ie: Match if suffix not present.  So, what im telling it to look for is any instance of % that is not followed by 2 hex characters, or any other invalid character.  The assumption is that anything that DOESN'T match this regex is a valid character entry.