# Regexp - Match any character except "Something.AnyChar"

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have a string:

**Input:**

> "Feature.. sklsd " AND klsdjkls 9290 "Feass . lskdk SDFSD __ ksdljsklfsd" NOT "Feuas" "Feature.lskd" OR PUT klasdkljf al9- .s.a, 9a0sd90209 .a,sdklf jalkdfj al;akd

---

I need to match any character except `OR`, `NOT`, `AND`, `"Feature.any_count_of_characters"`

the last one is important this start with: `"Feature.`

This is followed by any number of characters and then ends with: `" character.`

I'm trying to solve this using `lookahead` or `lookbehind` but I can get the expected output, only a portion of characters that I don't want.

My expected **output** is

> "Feature.. sklsd " AND **klsdjkls 9290** "Feass . lskdk SDFSD __ ksdljsklfsd" NOT "Feuas" "Feature.lskd" OR **PUT klasdkljf al9- .s.a, 9a0sd90209 .a,sdklf jalkdfj al;akd**

All that is in black.

To test it i'm using these links:

```
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
http://regexpal.com/
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Check this link http://regexr.com?37v36

inside the link i get matched some expression. But i don't need the expression that matched. i need the inverse, how i can get it?

Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Can you do another example?  I'm really not understanding what you mean by `any charcter except OR, NOT, AND, "Feature.any_count_of_characters"`

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956010/c-sharp-regular-expression-excluding-a-string) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116819/regular-expression-to-exclude-set-of-keywords) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241463/regex-exclude-matched-patterns) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781473/excluding-certain-patterns-in-a-regex) ...

Comment: Thanks for your help O.R. Mapper. But i still having the same problem because i need the opposite of that i get. Let me edit my question. (I'm using Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
\s*(?:AND|OR|NOT|"[^"]+")\s*
```

but do a replace operation.  That will leave what you want.

Comment: mjm.. nice.. i'm searching another way to do this.. but this works for now thanks. the thing is that i try to get a regexp because i need that in a group.. thats why i need inverse. i'll search in what other way i can get the inverse.

Comment: Why do you need it in a group?  Think about what you will do with the results and there may be an easy way of handling that issue with the result in a variable

Comment: mm i think this in a group because i need to replace all text that are in the groups. Now i can replace text that match with \s*(?:AND|OR|NOT|"[^"]+")\s* with some custom string. But i need to match the inverse because i need to replace too with other custom string.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that look behinds can not have arbitrary lengths, but you need that. There are work arounds, but a simpler approach is to use a capturing group:

```
"Feature\.[^"]*" (?:OR|NOT|AND) ([^"])
```

And your target will be in group 1 of the match.

Comment: Well, thats doesn't work because that code match the "Feature...." etc... but i need to match any character except "Feature...." etc. so the inverse. Please check the edit question. thanks for help.